# Driving single 1W LED from 5V

Tags: voltage, led, power, current, driver

I need to drive 2 high power LEDs (1 watt each) from a 5 volt supply. My current solution is to use a separate current source for each LED, each of which is made of a mosfet and bjt. This is only as efficient as a series resistor, and the LEDs each have a 2.7V drop and 350mA draw, so with a 3V supply it's around 75% efficient which is not terrible. However, with a 5V supply this drops to around 50%. An additional requirement is that the whole circuit be small and light enough to wear.

I need a new solution which is at least 80% efficient when operating from a 5V supply. The trouble is, almost all the driver chips I can find are designed for driving long series strings of LEDs from higher supply voltages. Can anyone recommend a chip or constant current source that might do the job?

Comment: You want a "boost" constant current driver. It uses an inductance to trade current for voltage.

Comment: So if I get your drift, I'd put the two LEDs in series and the boost constant current driver would typically have a voltage output around 6V? (obviously it would swing around as to keep the current constant)

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a boost converter that can make about 5½ V at 350 mA from 5 V in.  That shouldn't be too hard to find.  At this low voltage and since efficiency matters, get one with synchronous rectification built in.

The more tricky part is arranging the feedback to get the current regulation you want.  At 350 mA, a 1 Ω low side current sense resistor would drop 350 mV, which represents about 6% loss.  500 mΩ would be less loss, and the resulting 175 mV signal at the current regulation point should be quite good enough.  You can amplify that by a fixed gain to get to whatever regulation feedback voltage the boost chip you pick needs.

Watch out for instability in the boost chip with a opamp in the feedback path.  A boost chip with external compenstation could be useful here.  You could over-compensate the boost chip for more stability.  LEDs don't cause any transients it has to respond to quickly, so no problem there.  Before doing any of that though, try with a ordinary 1 MHz or 10 MHz opamp and see if it works.  Additional compenstation may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone recommend a chip or constant current source that might do the job?

those little smps modules from ebay can be easily reconfigured as a constant current source to drive those leds. a great compromise between efficiency and cost.

the challenge with that approach here is that the input voltage is very low. so you will need to watch out for a chip that can work with such input voltage levels.

Comment: Those eBay boards will not be "small and light enough to wear".  Getting 80% efficiency is not easy for 5V in. with 2.7 out, doubt the eBay boards would do the job.  3.3v  input is easier.

Answer (score -1):

- Capable of driving White LEDs up to 600 mA
- Low profile, very small sized inductor and output capacitor
- 94% Efficiency for 3.3 V Output at 200 mA from 2.5 V Input
- 88% Efficiency for 3.3 V Output at 500 mA from 2.5 V Input
- Integrated Low−Battery Detector
- Output Voltage from 1.5 V to 5.0 V Adjustable
- High Switching Frequency, up to 1.2 Mhz
- $2.00 BOM

[image]

Schematic matches PCB image
Inductor dimensions .24" x .22" x .055" height
[image]